# Where should I post question about practical experience using a "framework" in an "unusual" context?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm working on a project where we need to have distributed synchronization between machines in a network.

Zookeeper, Curator and Exhibitor seem to fulfil our needs. However, we are mostly a Windows, C# and .Net shop.

During the last few days, I've been struggling with various options for using Zookeeper from a .Net client. The "official" [.net binding](https://github.com/ewhauser/zookeeper), [CuratorIKVM](https://github.com/scottlowe/CuratorIkvm), and Zookeeper's [REST API](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/tree/trunk/src/contrib/rest).

All my tests were quite frustrating (but part of my frustration is certainly due to my lack of Java knowledge) and my general feeling is that Zookeeper doesn't fit very well in the .Net world.

So I'm wondering if others have followed the same track and if there is any practical experience of using Zookeeper from C# in a production context. Getting some pieces of advise from people having that experience would be nice.

I feel that kind of question doesn't belong to SO. Is there any place on the SE multiverse where it would fit?